# Tokyo Cabinet and cygwin

Tags: regex, cygwin, dbm

I am trying to install [**Tokyo Cabinet**](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet) under Windows Cygwin but when I run `./configure` I get the following error:

```
configure: error: regex.h is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a stock Cygwin installation, this can be fixed by installing the `gcc4-core` package. Make sure to check `Select required packages (RECOMMENDED)`.

However if you are trying to cross compile you will need to [**install PCRE**](http://kemovitra.blogspot.com/2009/07/mingw-porting-gnu-regex-to-windows.html).